# How to move compile-time logic to client code

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I have the following code:

```
void processUserInput(const std::string& input)
{
    if ("apples" == input)
    {
        Apple apple{};
        Processor<Apple> processor{};
        processor.process(apple);
    }
    else if ("raspberries" == input)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So my `processUserInput` is probably a method inside some `UserInputProcessor` class. I want client code to be able to tell the `UserInputProcessor` how the matching logic looks like. It will still be at compile time, but just in a different place such that the user of `UserInputProcessor` never needs to go inside the class, but be able to tell it from outside how to do the matching.

Basically something like pseudocode `userInputProcessor.match("apples", Apple)` where `Apple` is a type. Or just give it the `Processor<Apple>` directly as an object, but then that's going to be a problem inside the `UserInputProcessor` how we can have the different processors in the same container. `std::any` does not solve it because at some point we'd need to convert it back into the original `Processor<Apple>` and we won't know what kind of `Processor<>` we're dealing with.

Ideas? Any kind of template magic or preprocessing trickery is appreciated!